# Listview w/ custom adapter not loading title array only 0's with Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android, android-listview, listadapter, navigation-drawer

Im looking for someone that can help me with my Navigation Drawer with a customer list adapter. Im having a issue with my Listview not populating the String arrays and my list header strings and instead loading some sort of resource id number.

Im new to listviews and just need someone that is more familiar to look over the below code to help me figure out why this is happening.

Thanks

[image]

### Code

### NsMenuAdapter

```
 public class NsMenuAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NsMenuItemModel> {

/*
 * public NsMenuAdapter(Context context, int resource, int
 * textViewResourceId, String[] objects) { super(context,
 * R.layout.ns_menu_row, textViewResourceId, objects); }
 */
public NsMenuAdapter(Context context) {
    super(context, 0);
}
public void addHeader(int title) {
    add(new NsMenuItemModel(title, -1, true));
}
public void addItem(int title, int icon) {
    add(new NsMenuItemModel(title, icon, false));
}
public void addItem(NsMenuItemModel itemModel) {
    add(itemModel);
}
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return getItem(position).isHeader ? 0 : 1;
}
@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    return !getItem(position).isHeader;
}
public static class ViewHolder {
    public final TextView textHolder;
    public final ImageView imageHolder;

    public ViewHolder(TextView text1, ImageView image1) {
        this.textHolder = text1;
        this.imageHolder = image1;
    }
}
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    NsMenuItemModel item = getItem(position);
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        int layout = R.layout.ns_menu_row;
        if (item.isHeader)
            layout = R.layout.ns_menu_row_header;

        view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(layout, null);

        TextView text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.menurow_title);
        ImageView image1 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.menurow_icon);
        view.setTag(new ViewHolder(text1, image1));
    }
    if (holder == null && view != null) {
        Object tag = view.getTag();
        if (tag instanceof ViewHolder) {
            holder = (ViewHolder) tag;
        }
    }
    if(item != null && holder != null)
    {
        if (holder.textHolder != null)
            //holder.textHolder.setText(item.title);
            holder.textHolder.setText(String.valueOf(item.title));

        if (holder.imageHolder != null) {
            if (item.iconRes > 0) {
                holder.imageHolder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.imageHolder.setImageResource(item.iconRes);
            } else {
                holder.imageHolder.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }
    return view;        
   }
 }
```

### NsMenuItemModel

```
public class NsMenuItemModel {

public int title;
public int iconRes;
public boolean isHeader;

public NsMenuItemModel(int title, int iconRes,boolean header) {
    this.title = title;
    this.iconRes = iconRes;
    this.isHeader=header;

}

public NsMenuItemModel(int title, int iconRes) {
    this(title,iconRes,false);
}
```

}

### MainActivity

```
    private ListView mDrawerList;
private DrawerLayout mDrawer;
private CustomActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private String[] menuItems;
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
private CharSequence mTitle;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);
     mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawer.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

    _initMenu();
    mDrawerToggle = new CustomActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawer);
    mDrawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

}

private void _initMenu() {
    NsMenuAdapter mAdapter = new NsMenuAdapter(this);

    mAdapter.addHeader(R.string.header1);
    menuItems = getResources().getStringArray(
            R.array.dashboard_array);
    String[] menuItemsIcon = getResources().getStringArray(
            R.array.ns_menu_items_icon);

    int res = 0;
    for (String item : menuItems) {

        int id_title = getResources().getIdentifier(item, "string",
                this.getPackageName());
        int id_icon = getResources().getIdentifier(menuItemsIcon[res],
                "drawable", this.getPackageName());

        NsMenuItemModel mItem = new NsMenuItemModel(id_title, id_icon);
        mAdapter.addItem(mItem);
        res++;
    }

    mAdapter.addHeader(R.string.header2);

    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    if (mDrawerList != null)
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

}

private class CustomActionBarDrawerToggle extends ActionBarDrawerToggle {

    public CustomActionBarDrawerToggle(Activity mActivity,DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout){
        super(
            mActivity,
            mDrawerLayout, 
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,
            R.string.drawer_open, 
            R.string.drawer_close);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
        getActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.solartools_gosolar_title));
        invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
        getActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.solartools_pvwatts_title));
        invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
    }
}

private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        String text= "menu click... should be implemented";
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, text , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mDrawer.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

    }

}
@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}
```

### Layouts

```
**ms_menu_row_header**

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="48dp"
android:gravity="center_vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/menurow_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text=""
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/menu_divider"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/menurow_title"
    android:src="#DADADC" />

  </RelativeLayout>

**ns_menu_row**

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/ns_menu_row"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" >

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menurow_icon"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/menurow_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
         />
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:background="#DADADC" />

  </LinearLayout>

 **activity_dashboard**

  <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    style="@style/ListViewAppTheme"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="#cecbce"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:dividerPadding="1dp" />

  </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

### Array

```
 <string-array name="dashboard_array">
    <item>Home</item>
    <item>Community</item>
    <item>Blog</item>
    <item>Website</item>
    <item>The latest</item>
    <item>News</item>        
    <item>Support</item>
</string-array>

<array name="ns_menu_items_icon">
    <item>ic_action_web_site</item>
    <item>ic_action_share</item>
    <item>ic_action_negative</item>
    <item>ic_action_web_site</item>
    <item>ic_action_new</item>
    <item>ic_action_negative</item>
    <item>ic_action_expand</item>
</array>
```

Answer (score 1):

> and instead loading some sort of resource id number.

What you see is what you should get based on your code. First of all, for the big number(21... which is a string id from your code), you get this because in your `getView()` method you use:

```
holder.textHolder.setText(String.valueOf(item.title));
```

`item.title` is the **id** of the string resource and you can't just pas it around expecting to get the actual string, you need to convert it before using. This could be done using:

```
holder.textHolder.setText(getContext().getResources().getString(item.title));
```

For the rows with the `0` text, that's happening because you don't setup the non header rows properly. You have the strings in an string array resource, `dashboard_array`, but when you build the adapter's items you use a for loop with:

```
int id_title = getResources().getIdentifier(item, "string", this.getPackageName());
```

This will not work because you're looking for a string resource by a name that only exists in a string array resource(so there's no `R.string.item_name_here`) which will return `0`, which you later insert as the text like you did for the header. So you either break that string array resources in 7 individual strings and use your current code(with the `getIdentifier()` method) or you change the way you handle the text for non header rows(to not use `item.title` for normal rows).

As a side note, you're not properly implementing the two types of rows for the `ListView`. The idea  is to implement the `getViewTypeCOunt` and `getItempViewType()` methods and then use them in the `getView()` method to inflate and set the proper row type. There're a lot of example out there on how to do this.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply, im working changing the code around, i'll update the code with my changes based on your suggestions.